# Counting Sort in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, counting-sort

I am trying to implement the Counting Sort in C++ without creating a function. This is the code that I've written so far, but the program doesn't return me any values. It doesn't give me any errors either. Therefore, what is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A[100], B[100], C[100], i, j, k = 0, n;

    cin >> n;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> A[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (A[i] > k)
        {
            k = A[i];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < k + 1; ++i)
    {
        C[i] = 0;
    }

    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        C[A[j]]++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    {
        C[i] += C[i - 1];
    }

    for (j = n; j > 0; --j)
    {
        B[C[A[j]]] = A[j];
        C[A[j]] -= 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << B[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "without creating a function": why?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what is your question. What do you expect to happen? :)

Comment: `C[i] += C[i - 1];` If `i` is starting from 0, you are going out of bounds.

Comment: please include the expected and actual output in the question, also hardcoded input will be required for us to reproduce the same as you are running

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're on the right track. You take input into `A`, find the largest value you'll be dealing with and then make sure you zero out that many values in your `C` array. But that's when things start to go wrong. You then do:

```
for (i = 0; i < k; ++i)
{
    C[i] += C[i - 1];
}

for (j = n; j > 0; --j)
{
    B[C[A[j]]] = A[j];
    C[A[j]] -= 1;
}
```

That first loop will always go out of bounds on the first iteration (`C[i-1]` when `i=0` will be undefined behavior), but even if it didn't I'm not sure what you have in mind here. Or in the loop after that for that matter.

Instead, if I were you, I'd create an `indx` variable to keep track of which index I'm next going to insert a number to (how many numbers I've inserted so far), and then I'd loop over `C` and for each value in `C`, I'd loop that many times and insert that many values of that index. My explanation may sound a little wordy, but that'd look like:

```
int indx = 0;
for(int x = 0; x <= k; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < C[x]; y++) {
        B[indx++] = x;
    }
}
```

If you replace the two loops above with this one, then everything should work as expected.

See a live example here: [ideone](https://ideone.com/f9dcZC)